# How to show a partial view on click of actionlink in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following two action links on a page:

```
@Html.ActionLink("User List","list");
@Html.ActionLink("Admin List","admin");
```

On their click I want to show/hide a partial view using jQuery. Help me with solution for this.

Comment: You'd better use ajax for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `Ajax.ActionLink` helper instead:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("User List","list", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "someDiv" });
@Ajax.ActionLink("Admin List","admin", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "someDiv" });
```

This assumes that the `list` and `admin` actions return partial views:

```
public ActionResult List()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

and the result of this partial view will be injected into a DOM element with `id="someDiv"`. Also for this to work don't forget to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: This is not working the div is not showing the patial view rather and also the UI is getting distorted after that.

Comment: Did you try debugging your controller code? Is the corresponding action being hit? Also you might use FireBug to analyze the AJAX request and the exact request/response sent over the wire as well as any possible errors.

Comment: Thanks it worked. This is something nice and a good and shorter solution to0 the problem. Thanku

Comment: If I redirect to some other page and then come back to the page where these two link buttons are then that links become disable and are not working. If I refresh the page then it is working. Why?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="test"></div>

@Ajax.ActionLink("User List","list", new AjaxOptions{ UpdateTargetId = "test" });
@Ajax.ActionLink("Admin List","admin", new AjaxOptions{ UpdateTargetId = "test" });
```